# Missing AmazonS3Client Bean when upgrading SpringCloud Finchley to RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I recently upgraded my SpringCloud project from Brixton to Finchley and everything was working just fine. I was working on Finchley.SR2 and I had no problems, but whenever I upgrade my project to Finchley.RELEASE (and this is the only change I make), the project fails to start.

The reason is that the project could not find the `AmazonS3Client` Bean:

```
...Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No qualifying bean of type 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client' available: 
      expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
        Dependency annotations: {}
```

These are my previous relevant configurations and classes:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    }

    ...

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.5.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.SR2"
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    ...
}

...
```

**S3Config.java** (The class that creates the AmazonS3/AmazonS3Client Bean)

```
...

@Configuration
public class S3Config {

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3() {
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**StorageService** (the class that fails to find the Bean)

```
...

@Service
public class StorageService {

    private final AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client;

    @Autowired
    public StorageService(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client) {
        this.amazonS3Client = amazonS3Client;
    }

    ...
}
```

And this is the only change I make to the **build.gradle** file when upgrading to Finchley.Release:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.RELEASE"
    }
}
```

I've tried looking for any missing library and tweaking all the configurations I can find, but none seem to take any effect.

Comment: This [implementation](https://gist.github.com/arthurportas/7b6e5ffb413a507fb84c#file-configuration-java) may help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Madushan Perera, but looking at the source code of the AmazonS3Client I noticed all the uses of an `AmazonS3Client` constructor are deprecated, so in the long term it may not be the best solution u_u

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a brief talk with the Spring maintainers, [a solution was found](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/353).

It seems I was at fault by assuming that a Bean of `AmazonS3` should always be found as an `AmazonS3Client` Bean just because one implements the other. It was just pure luck that it worked on previous Spring versions.

The proper way to create an `AmazonS3Client` would be the following:

```
@Configuration
public class S3Config {

    @Bean
    public static AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client() {
        return (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .build();
    }
}
```